# How to show the '2013-10-20' in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I don't understand this code:

```
moment('2013-10-18').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2013-10-18
moment('2013-10-19').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2013-10-19
moment('2013-10-20').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2013-10-19
moment('2013-10-21').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2013-10-21
moment('2013-10-22').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2013-10-22
```

This is a bug or my mistake?

http://jsfiddle.net/9CRCz/

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9CRCz/2/

Comment: Umm.. What's the question?

Comment: I don't see the problem?

Comment: When I view the jsfiddle, the time output look correct.  might be an issue with timezone.  What timezone are you in?

Comment: Looks fine in CEST (GMT+2)

Comment: My timezone is GMT -3:00 (America/Sao Paulo)

Comment: the moment('2013-10-20').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); show '2013-10-19' for me

Comment: @MarcosYoshihiroNakamine on OSX I adjusted my laptop to Brasilia Standard Time (currently 17:19:33) and cannot reproduce

Comment: What does `console.log(moment('2013-10-20').toDate())` show you?

Comment: Sat Oct 19 2013 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)

Comment: @MarcosYoshihiroNakamine: Strange...

Comment: I tested in Tor browser and show correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Sunday October 20th, Brazil enters Daylight Savings Time. The clocks change at midnight, jumping forward one hour. This means that the date you have given (which defaults to midnight since you gave no time) is interpreted incorrectly. If you output the time, you might see something like 23:00:00 instead of the expected midnight.

To fix this, use `'2013-10-20 12:00:00'`- midday is certainly not going to be affected by DST enough to change the date! So this will guarantee that the date emerges untouched.

Comment: I was just writing this, you beat me to it! :)   We've already discussed this in [moment issue #1069](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1069).  The main problem is as you described with Brazil's DST at midnight.  The secondary problem is that some browsers will adjust forward, while others (like Chrome) will adjust backward.  Your workaround is spot on.